# mysql: combine 3 query in 1 - group by

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a database with 100 users and their login time (for 1 user there are 10000 rows).
so how can i pick 3 users (by their userid)  and then  get only last time they logged in

> (id, userid, timestamp)

```
SELECT userid,timestamp FROM users WHERE userid='22'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
SELECT userid,timestamp FROM users WHERE userid='15'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
SELECT userid,timestamp FROM users WHERE userid='42'  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

i tried also **GROUP BY** but is not showing last timestamp for each user

```
SELECT userid,timestamp FROM users WHERE userid IN (22,15,42)' GROUP BY userid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the last login time is determined by the `ID` then:

```
SELECT u.userid, u.timestamp
FROM users u
WHERE u.userid IN (22,15,42) 
  AND u.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM users WHERE userid = u.userid)
```

or if it is determined by `timestamp`:

```
SELECT userid, max(timestamp) timestamp
FROM users 
WHERE userid IN (22,15,42) 
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

USE MAX of timestamp

```
SELECT userid,MAX(`timestamp`) 
FROM table1 
WHERE userid in(15,22,42) GROUP BY userid;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int , userid int , `timestamp` timestamp)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 (id, userid, `timestamp`) VALUES  (1,15,NOW()),
> (2,15,NOW() + INTERVAL 1 Minute),(3,15,NOW() + INTERVAL 5 Minute),
> (4,22,NOW() + INTERVAL 1 Minute),
> (5,22,NOW() + INTERVAL 2 Minute),(6,22,NOW() + INTERVAL 6 Minute),
> (7,42,NOW() + INTERVAL 1 Minute),
> (8,42,NOW() + INTERVAL 2 Minute),(9,22,NOW() + INTERVAL 7 Minute);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT userid,MAX(`timestamp`) FROM table1 WHERE userid in(15,22,42) GROUP BY userid;
> ```
>
> ```
> userid | MAX(`timestamp`)   
> -----: | :------------------
>     15 | 2020-03-10 23:49:55
>     22 | 2020-03-10 23:51:55
>     42 | 2020-03-10 23:46:55
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | userid | timestamp          
> -: | -----: | :------------------
>  1 |     15 | 2020-03-10 23:44:55
>  2 |     15 | 2020-03-10 23:45:55
>  3 |     15 | 2020-03-10 23:49:55
>  4 |     22 | 2020-03-10 23:45:55
>  5 |     22 | 2020-03-10 23:46:55
>  6 |     22 | 2020-03-10 23:50:55
>  7 |     42 | 2020-03-10 23:45:55
>  8 |     42 | 2020-03-10 23:46:55
>  9 |     22 | 2020-03-10 23:51:55
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=91dec5a220937c9343f4f89f6e46714e)*